# How to slow down my program and getting user input?

Tags: c++, sfml, game-loop

To get user input with SFML I use this function

```
char SFMLDisplayManager::handleEvents()
{
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Z))
    return ('z');
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
    return ('s');
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Q))
    return ('q');
  if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
    return ('d');
  return (0);
}
```

Then, to slow down my program, I use

```
sf::sleep((sf::milliseconds(150)));
```

This works fine but when I press a key quickly, sometimes I don't get the input.
I suppose this happens because I press they key during the sleep.

But I don't know how to solve this.

Have an idea ? Thanks

Comment: You should be reading the SFML tutorials. You will always have problems if you handle time-management like you do know. You need to use another method. Seriously, read the tutorials, they are good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reduce the sleep time.

If you have the program in while loop without sleep it does take 100% of your cpu time, but setting the sleep value to just `1ms` will make it use it about 0%.

### EDIT

Generally it is a good idea to have the logic loop separated from the drawing loop(calling the logic loop only every `n ms`), or computing everything in the game based on the delta time (the time that has passed from the last frame).

You can read more about game loops and sfml here https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Basic-Game-Engine#gameloop

Comment: I cannot reduce the sleep time, my game will be way too fast if I do this.

Comment: You shouldn't process logic graphics and input at the same speed. Logic should be done in a fixed interval, input as fast as possible. Graphics should be either fixed at some fps or pushed to the limit.

Comment: I dont understand how I can separate the logic graphics speed and the input speed.

Answer (score -1):

You Can avoid key repetition using

http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Window.php#aef9f2b14c10ecba8a8df95dd51c5bb73

And catch the event key pressed.

That can be useful in order to create for instance a text box where the user can write.

Comment: please add some code here - providing link only is not an answer